# how to execute app as system user?

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

I want to write in /sys/class/camera/rear_flash but I don't have a permissions, the file has read and write permissions as user "system" and any user within the group "radio" (rw- rw- r--). Can I launch my app as "system" user or user within "radio" group without being root?

Answer (score 0):

To run your App as System you have install it as follow:

Copy your APK in SD Card and executing these adb commands

```
adb shell
su

cd sdcard/
mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
cat YOURAPP.apk > /system/app/YOURAPP.apk


chmod 644 /system/app/YOURAPP.apk
reboot
```

Comment: The problem I see is that I need to have a rooted device. Without root, could I do it?

Comment: No, You don't... It should be rooted... I'm sorry